# get information about a particular object

Tags: git

I'm trying to implement a [git-remote-helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote-helpers). So far I've managed to make an ineficient push :

I use `git log --format=%H <commitHash>` to know what commits I need to send

Then `git cat-file -p <commitHash>^{tree}` to know what objects I need send with a commit (I'm putting the list of all object in a set to avoid sending twice the same)

I have some trouble with `fetch`, because I don't know what objects I need to take from the remote, I know the last commit (pointed by `refs/heads/myBranch`). But my previous commands don't work during the fetch because it is missing dependent object (which are the objects I'm trying to get info about to be able to fetch them)

- My question is : What command(s) should I use to be able to read an `object` and know what is/are its parent(s) (for a commit) and what other objects it points to (for a commit or a tree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you intend to do with all of this, which affects the "right way"—though it might be better to say *most efficient* way—to go about actually doing it.  Nonetheless, `git cat-file` is pretty much *the* "outside program" way to access everything in Git.  To read an object, you need a name for it—the SHA-1 hash is the obvious name, since it's *the* name, but anything suitable for `git rev-parse` suffices—and `git cat-file`, in its various incarnations, will dump it out, possibly with some formatting applied, or even with `--textconv` or `--path` filtering.

Note that you need to operate recursively: obtaining a commit gets you its `tree`, all of its `parent`s, the author and committer, and the log.  Obtaining a `tree` objects gets you its constituent sub-trees and blobs, but each sub-tree may have more sub-trees, which is where the recursion sets in.  The paths to apply to final blobs (including symlinks and gitlinks) are determined via the recursion, i.e., if the top level tree was *T* and you found subtree *D1* whose component name is *N1*, containing subtree *D2* named *N2*, containing blob *B* named *N3*, the path name under which *B* is stored is `N1/N2/N3`.  (You may not need to care about paths, depending on what you're doing—e.g., Git's own push and fetch operations don't have to care since it's just storing these objects in the repository, and path name construction occurs later, during `git checkout` for instance.)

Similarly, obtaining an annotated tag object gets you its `object`, but this may be another annotated tag object, and you have to keep following these IDs until you reach a non-tag (though there's no *recursion* involved this time since these do not nest).

All that said, `git rev-list` actually implements all of this goop for Git's own transports.  This is why `git rev-list` has `--objects` and related options: you—or Git—can direct it to find the object sets to fetch or push, using the hash IDs stored with various reference names.